# Looping in Excel to calculate the yearly change

Tags: excel, vba, loops, conditional-statements

I was able to loop through each column (ticker) and the (vol) and work out the total stock volume for each one(e.g.. AAB has an amount, AAF has an amount and so on). I now need to work out the yearly change for each which will involve subtracting the last value of the close range and the first value of the open range for each ticker(AAB, AAF etc.). So I'm trying to work out how to write the correct code.

This is my code so far;

[image]

```
Dim Table_R As Integer
Table_R = 2

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For I = 2 To LastRow

        If Cells(I + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(I, 1).Value Then

    Ticker_symbol = Cells(I, 1).Value
    
    Total_Vol = Total_Vol + Cells(I, 7).Value
    
    Range("I" & Table_R).Value = Ticker_symbol
    
    Range("L" & Table_R).Value = Total_Vol
    
    Table_R = Table_R + 1
    
    Total_Vol = 0
       
Else
    Total_Vol = Total_Vol + Cells(I, 7).Value
    
End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.